# Notifications are not getting in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, iphone, nsnotifications, ios9.2

Notifications are not getting after upgrade to iOS9.2 but up to iOS9.1 there is no such type of issue. But I didn't understand where was the problem. Is it iOS9.2 problem ? Can anyone help me out from this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not providing enough information for us to help you. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Sorry for that but simply I will say I have an issue i.e I am not getting notifications in iOS9.2 but in previous versions there is no such type of problem.

Comment: Is this an issue with an application that you're writing or is this an issue globally? If it's with your app, please provide the code that you're using to handle the inbound notification.

Comment: @cynicaljoy- Actually it was not new one. Already it was working in all previous versions. But the issue was raised in iOS9.2.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4s seems to be having little discrepancies in ios 9.2 like notification icons are coming but no vibrations or sound alerts are there. Are you using a iPhone 4s?

Comment: No I am using iPhone5.