# remote notification are not displayed in ios using FCM

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

after deploying FCM cloud messaging which is the upgrading version of GCM cloud messaging as mentioned https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client so we moved to integrate FCM in our app using pod as mentioned https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications i follow up every step in the tutorial here is what happening the remote notification had been received well in both state **Background State** and **active state** but the main problem that i faced is the notification does appear in the notification bar here is my code that i am using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



    float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if(ver >= 8 && ver<9)
    {
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

        }
    }else if (ver >=9){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];


    }
    else{
        //iOS6 and iOS7 specific code
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
    }
    // ma tensa google maps
    [FIRApp configure];
    [self connectToFcm];

}


- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {


        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[@"gcm.message_id"]);


//    
//    if (application.applicationState == active) {
//        <#statements#>
//    }
    // Pring full message.
    NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

   // [[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];


}


- (void)connectToFcm {
    [[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to connect to FCM. %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Connected to FCM.");

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"registeredToFCM"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];




  // i used the method since not all the time app register for fcm so when 
 //the complete launching and did not register //
//for fcm the app request to register fro fcm again//

        }
    }];
}
```

here some link that i searched for to solve my problem before moving here [Notifications are not getting in iOS 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34528733/notifications-are-not-getting-in-ios-9-2) , [FCM background notifications not working in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899712/fcm-background-notifications-not-working-in-ios), and [Push notifications are not working in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718273/push-notifications-are-not-working-in-ios-9) but i could not solve my issue

> Forgot to tell you that the phone is ringing and vibrating when the notification had been received.

hope any one help **Happy Coding** !!

Comment: sidenote: to not forget maps, add  `#warning ma tensa google maps`

Comment: what kind of payload are you sending with the push? Can you provide an example of a push payload (JSON maybe?)?

Comment: From the fcm console

Comment: is it plain text? JSON? and did you check notifications in your devices settings?

Comment: the payload is json

Comment: please provide an example of the payload

Comment: notification =     {
        badge = 0;
        body = hello;
        e = 1;
        sound = default;
        sound2 = default;
    };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115705/discussion-between-zakaria-darwish-and-hussein).

Comment: check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html)

Comment: have you get the device token

Answer (score 0):

If you want the notification to show up you have to set "priority":"high". Like so:

```
"to":"TOKEN ID",
"notification" : {
  "body" : "test"
},
"priority": "high"
}
```